# UITableViewCell with custom control in content view + text wrap title

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have my own class

```
TableViewCellRaing: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet weak var outletCellRating: RaingControl!
}
```

incidently, rating control was inspired by:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson5.html

I have placed he control in "Content View"

However, long titles are covering the rating control which is not good.

I have therefore tried this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableViewm cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  //...
  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rating", forIndexPath: indexPath);
  //...
  cell!.textLabel!.lineBreakmode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping;
  cell!.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0;
  //...
}
```

This does make the title break and span multiple lines, but they break too late (i.e. it is like it does not see/consider the "content view" containing the rating conrol)

Here's a screenshot of my storyboard

[image]

I am not sure what is the best way to proceed from here - I am wondering if I did something wrong when creating my custom cell class? Or if I could create it a different way which would make this issue resolve itself?

There's also an issue with cell height, but if I first get the custom control issue resolved, I can probably calculate that myself.

Comment: Post screenshot and your storyboard.

Comment: @ArunGupta hereby done - let me know if you need anything else

Comment: There are a lot of things you can do. You want that light blue label to be full width of the cell and to have the cell expand to fit all the text correct?

Comment: I am guessing you by "light blue label" mean he color box to the right - that's the rating control being covered by the title runtime even which is what I want to avoid (!)

Comment: Please create a sample and share the sample of code as link. For eg, dropbox link. This will help us in resolving your issue.

Comment: You can't use the default textLabel for this, follow my answer, it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give height, width, top, and trailing constraints to you ratingControl.

You can't use the default textlabel for this, create a new label to the left of your ratingControl.

Give leading, top and bottom to container margins (important, not to the superview itself but to the view margins, otherwise you can have some autolayout warnings with dynamic height cells), trailing (to the ratingControl, horizontal spacing) and height >= actualHeight contraints to your label.

Then set tableView estimatedRowHeight to the average height of you prototype cells (or 44.0 is good anyway) and tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

cell!.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0; is correct.

At this point it should work...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The #1 main problem sounds to be I tried to extend/use the cell type I inherited from. (i.e. can not use default text label) I will try do as you suggest - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 labels above your rating view and probably all 3 must be giving you issue. Simple way is to give a constant height and trancate the large string but you probably dont need that. So instead of giving a height to label give vertical constraint to your label and rating view properly. And use

```
 self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

and autolayout should do everything then.

Comment: he screenshot depicts 3 prototype cells. My question is regarding the bottom one - the one called "scores" in the screenshot.

There's the title and detail labels (my cusom cell inherits from uitableViewCell - maybe that is really a mistake do it that way...) to the left of my raing control (the cyan light blue box to the right placed in "content view")